# What's the meaning of () => () => {} inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I've found the following snippet in an application. What's the meaning of the double () in this snippet? What effect does it have? It'd seem it's a function that calls function, but why?

```
useEffect(
    () => () => {
      dispatch(fetchData());
    },
    []
  );
```

Thanks

Comment: its a function that returns a function.

Comment: indeed. So it means that when the component gets unmounted, fetchData is called

Comment: `() => () => {/* body */}` is an arrow function that returns a function when called. Together with `useEffect` and an empty dependency list that means that the returned function will be called when the component unmounts.

Comment: Thanks - duuuh - I didn't spot it's a cleanup function in this context!